# Jquery to set img dimensions from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

Im doing a nav.

Its a ul list. the 'a' tags and 'span's are in the same space and the span contains an image that is hidden.
The image does fadeIn/fadeOut which is successful.
Im trying to set the width of the img/span to the width of the li(the parent)

i cant seem to friggin do it. please help.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Web<br />Design</a><span><img src="images/nav-over.png"  height="100px" /></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Graphic<br />Design</a><span><img src="images/nav-over.png"  height="100px" /></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our<br />Work</a><span><img src="images/nav-over.png" height="100px" /></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">SEO</a><span><img src="images/nav-over.png" height="100px" /></span></li>
</ul>
```

this was kinda on the right path...

```
var h = $('#nav li img').parent().height();
var w = $('#nav li img').parent().width();
$('#nav li img').width(w).height(h);
```

but it set all of the #nav li span height and width the same and not from the parent...

then i've tried this :

```
$('#nav li span').each(function(){$(this).parent().width()});
$('#nav li span img').each(function(){$(this).parent().width()});
```

which i know is poorly structured but i was just testing. but no it didn't work...

so for each #nav li span and #nav li img i want to set the width to the corresponding parent(li) width.

i think i explained this correctly. lol. thanks.

heres the css

```
 #nav {
    list-style:none; width:608px; height:100px; display:block; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative
}
#nav li {
    background:url(images/nav-div.jpg) right top no-repeat; float:left; text-align:center;height:100px;
}
#nav li a {
    color:#565555; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing:10px; line-height:25px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none;height:100px; display:block; padding:0 19px 0 19px; position:relative; top:0; left:0;z-index:900
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color:#eaeaea   
}

#nav li span {
    position:relative; top:-100px; left:0; z-index:800; opacity:0.0;
}
```

Comment: Your last css definition hides the image.  Why do you have it?  If you are hiding the image, do height and width matter?

Comment: the first paragraph says... theres a fadeIn/fadeOut that is working correctly already... i've been editing the css so let me edit it here too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.width()` where you have `.each()`, and use `.closest("li")` instead of `.parent()`, and don't forget the `return` statements:

```
$('#nav li span img').width(function () { return $(this).closest("li").width(); });
$('#nav li span img').height(function () { return $(this).closest("li").height(); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KzhgQ/

**Edit:** Here's a more efficient version that prevents looping the images twice (thanks natedavisolds) :

```
$('#nav li span img').each(function () {
    var img = $(this);
    var listItem = img.closest("li");
    img.width(listItem.width()).height(listItem.height());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KzhgQ/1/

Comment: +1 I really like this solution too. Although will the `closest` find be run twice for every object?

Comment: @natedavisolds - Yes, good call.  That could be prevented by using `.each()` instead.

Comment: ah awesome. this worked, as well as others. i was having an issue that is hard to explain. i wound up just presetting the width of the image with css `#nav li span img {width:10px}` so it wouldnt stretch the li before the script ran. ah its hard to describe. but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Call me crazy, but couldn't/shouldn't you be doing this with CSS?:

```
#nav li img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: hmm. it works for anything 100% width of the image and over but it doesn't seem to work for a width under 100% of the image

Comment: @AlexAnonymous - If it's compatible with your layout, try setting either the img or its parent span to `position: absolute`.  That should resolve the issue with a li smaller than the img.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the CSS is set correctly (ie. block elements).

```
$('#nav li').each(function() {
  var $li = $(this);

  $li.find('span, span img').css({ width: $li.width(), height: $li.height()});
});
```

should work but untested.